# Word for releasing oneself from a hug

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I'm looking for a more physical description, so ignoring "disengaged" for this purpose. But wouldn't mind hearing why it might still be a good option.

> "You were almost torn apart!" Fabian said and hugged him.
>   Christoph released himself from the hug. "Did you see how cunning they were?"

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: How about "extricate"?

Comment: He _broke free_ of/from the hug?

Comment: You found it: _release_. You can consider _pull back_ also.

Comment: +1 on @Aaron's suggestion. In the (mainly humourous) settings that I've seen this in writing, it's usually phrased as "he extricated himself with difficulty from the crushing hug", or something to that effect.

Comment: *Disengage* oneself.

Answer (score 2):

If looking for a more physical description  [Thesaurus.com](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/disengage?s=t) offers:

detach

disconnect

disentangle

extricate

liberate.

But according to Dictionary.com [disengage](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/disengage) is not a bad choice:

```
verb (used with object), disengaged, disengaging.
1.to release from attachment or connection; loosen; unfasten:
to disengage a clutch.
2.to free (oneself) from an engagement, pledge, obligation, etc.:
He accepted the invitation, but was later forced to disengage himself.
3.Military. to break off action with (an enemy).
verb (used without object), disengaged, disengaging.
4.to become disengaged; free oneself.
```

However, I still feel that [release](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/release?s=t) is the best choice:

1.
to free from confinement, bondage, obligation, pain, etc.; let go:
to release a prisoner; to release someone from a debt.
2.
to free from anything that restrains, fastens, etc.:
to release a catapult.